# Rails 3 SSL on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, e-commerce

I am currently developing am e-commerce app in Rails 3.0.9 and it is hosted on Heroku.

Ideally I would like to set 'Hostname based SSL' (http://addons.heroku.com/ssl), but Heroku charges a fee of $20/month which seems a bit steep for me right now.

Heroku does offer a free SSL solution by piggybacking off their certificate, however you would have to use their domain (https://yourapp.heroku.com)

I was thinking I would direct my payment page to this URL and then redirect the user back to my custom URL after the transaction has been processed. The problems I'm have with using this solution are:

1. When you redirect the user back to the custom url after the transaction, my flash message will not be displayed as it is tied to the cookie of the heroku URL. How can I send the flash message back to the custom domain?
2. If the user clicks on any of the menu links on the payment page, they will be sent to a page hosted on the Heroku URL. Since all my links are relative to the root domain. Is there a way of forcing all URLs generated (I am using 'url_for' links in my menu) to use the full custom domain urls?

Unless someone can suggest an alternate solution altogether?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't expect to make more than $20/month you probably shouldn't be worrying about selling stuff in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
url_for(:only_path => false, :host => 'your-app.heroku.com', :protocol => :https)
```

Comment: well, I kind of want to intervene at a higher level, and only when the host is 'myapp.heroku.com' do I want the full URLS back to my custom domain. Is there a way to override the URL helper at force only_path false on all links?

Comment: if you provide a :host options, it will go full path by default

Comment: I know, but is there a way to add a before_filter or something that will add the host to ALL urls so I don't have to go through all my code and add :host everywhere I create a link?